# html table rows slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

In a page i am populating an HTML table where it may have random number of rows from 1 to 100. Irrespective of the number of rows I need to show only 10 rows of that table in one view and next 10 slides up after 5 seconds.

Sample table structure

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Competition</th>
    <th>Adam</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tableslide'>
  <tr>
    <td>Swimming</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Running</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sample</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mean</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acomon</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>server</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sample</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried with a sample code which shows the first 10 records but then it shows remaining all in one shot. I want to slice the total no of rows by 10 and show in each slides.

```
$(function () {
    var selectors = [
        ":lt(10)",
        ":gt(9)"
    ];
    var $tableslide = $("#tableslide").children(selectors[1]).hide().end();
    var state = false;
    setInterval(function () {
        var s = state;
        $tableslide.children(selectors[+s]).fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
            $tableslide.children(selectors[+!s]).fadeIn();
        });
        state = !state;
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are like a lot of ways to achieve this. Something with your selectors is not right and IMO you are doing it too complicated and hard to understand. Here is a working code:

```
$(function () {
    var $children = $("#tableslide").children();
    var step = 10, total = $children.length, currentStart = 0;

    // hide all
    $children.hide();

    // buffer to know what was shown, you could also go with :visible
    var $lastVisibleItems = $children.slice(currentStart, currentStart + step).show();

    setInterval(function () {
             $lastVisibleItems.fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
            currentStart += step;
            $lastVisibleItems = $children.slice(currentStart, currentStart + step).fadeIn();
          if (currentStart + step >= $children.length) {
            // reset to beginning, actually -step because it will because 0 after +step
            currentStart = -step;
          }
      });
    }, 3000);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpcy7s5h/5/)

**Explanation:**

1. First buffer all children elements
2. Set up your step, i.e. visible items at once.
3. Set up your current start, i.e. in any moment the items **[currentStart, currentStary + step)** are visible. You use `slice` to get a subarray of children
4. In the interval call just hide the last visible items (you have them in the buffer variable already, no need to traverse DOM). Increment the current start with the step, show the new items, and buffer them again.
5. If your end index (current start + step) is equal or greater to all the children count, then reset to zero (or clear the interval if you want to stop the animation)

**UPDATE:**

Since the question now includes dynamic population of the table via ajax here is the new code:

```
$(function () {
    var interval;
    var $table = $("#tableslide"), $children = $table.children();
    var step = 10, total = $children.length, currentStart = 0;

    function startInterval() {
      return setInterval(function () {
            currentStart += step;
          if (currentStart + step > $children.length) {
                // you have reached the end and you will not render a whole page so clear here
                clearInterval(interval); 
                interval = null;
              } else {
                $lastVisibleItems.fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
                        $lastVisibleItems = $children.slice(currentStart, currentStart + step).fadeIn();
                    });
              }

        }, 3000);
    }

    function restoreInterval() {
            if (!interval) {
            // you have stopped your timer, hence start it again, without changing the currentStart
            interval = startInterval();
          } else {
            // do nothing
          }
    }

    // hide all
    $children.hide();

    // buffer to know what was shown, you could also go with :visible
    var $lastVisibleItems = $children.slice(currentStart, currentStart + step).show();

    interval = startInterval();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/testurl',
        type: 'POST',
        //complete: function(result) { //use for testing
        success: function(result) {
                // modify your DOM with the server response. in my case add 10 dummy rows
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                $table.append($("<tr><td>Ajax row " + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td></tr>").hide());
            }
            // add rows to table and do not forget to modify the varuiable $children
            $children = $("#tableslide").children();

            // Restore the interval
            restoreInterval();
        }
    })
});
```

P.S. This is now a little bit more complex code and I think you will be more confused but I hope it will be helpful. Replace the `success` with `complete`
so you can test it. **No matter how many ajax calls you make it will work, you can even make ajax calls from the interval function if you detect like you are 1 or 2 pages near the end.**

Comment: can i call it from a ajax success

Comment: If table is dynamically populated with ajax, you have to check on the 5. step if you have reached the end index. If yes, you clear the interval, then on ajaxSuccess you start the interval again, if ONLY you have stopped it already (so keep track on whether or not the interval is active). This sync is needed because you do not know which will be faster -> the setInterval going to the end or the ajax call to fetch new rows.
Update: also you might want to stop 1 step before the end so you do not display a non-full page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @antanta's answer - There are many ways to achieve this, here's my solution (using `show` and `hide` instead of fade):

```
$('table tr:gt(10)').hide();

setInterval(function() {

var last = $('table tr:visible:last')
$('table tr').hide();
(last.next().length ? last.nextAll(':lt(10)', ':not(:visible)') : last.siblings(':lt(10)')).show();
}, 5000);
```

Explanation:

hide all but the first 10 columns, then every 5 seconds get the last visible `tr` element and show its next 10 siblings, if it has no next siblings, then show first 10 siblings.

```js
$('table tr:gt(10)').hide();

setInterval(function() {

var last = $('table tr:visible:last')
$('table tr').hide();
(last.next().length ? last.nextAll(':lt(10)', ':not(:visible)') : last.siblings(':lt(10)')).show();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Competition</th>
    <th>Adam</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tableslide'>
  <tr>
    <td>Swimming</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Running</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sample</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mean</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acomon</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>server</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sample</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>goto</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One issue here is th are not fixed. it disappear after first slide

Comment: $('#tableslide tr:gt(10)').hide();

setInterval(function() {

var last = $('#tableslide tr:visible:last')
$('#tableslide tr').hide();
(last.next().length ? last.nextAll(':lt(10)', ':not(:visible)') : last.siblings(':lt(10)')).show();
}, 3000);

Comment: this fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: One more issue which i am facing is that this html table is dynamically populated in ajax call. I made a fn and put our code inside it and called. i am not getting correct result when i call our jquery code in success of ajax. The things becomes messy..